# How do I write JavaScript that checks the number of chars in a sentence?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a script that checks the number of characters (excluding whitespace) in a sentence. For example: "this is a sentence" would be 15 characters. If the sentence contains a break like '.' it should be counted as a different sentence.

I have started writing the script but I think I need some help.

```
function(sen) {
  return sen.split('.').forEach(function(part) { part.match(/\s*/).result })
}
```

Comment: In case it matters and you didn't know: `''.length === 6` (not 3!). So any solution using `.length` on a string will fail to accommodate things like (but not limited to) emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Discounting emojis) Use a regex replace on the whitespaces so you clear them out first..

```
sen.replace(/\s*/g, '')
```

and then split the sentence and count the number of characters

```
function sentenceCounter(sen) {
  return sen.replace(/\s*/g, '').split('.').map(e => e.length)
}
```

Thats all you should need really, this should return a list of numbers corresponding to the length of your sentences

Answer (score 3):

Split by a period and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `length` property:

```js
function check(sen) {
  return sen.split('.').map(e => e.length)
}
console.log(check("Hello. World"))
```

If you only want the length of the first sentence, split by a period, get the first item and return its `length` property:

```js
function check(sen) {
  return sen.split('.')[0].length;
}
console.log(check("Hello. World"))
```

Comment: @t.deeeerp How does it not? Can you provide me a test case where it would produce an incorrect result?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = 'this is first sentence. this is second sentence';
let sentence = str.split('.');
let result = {};
sentence.forEach((value, index) => {
  result[index + 1] = value.length;
});
console.log(result);
```

The output will contain character length with respect to the sentence number.

Answer (score 0):

This function will  calculate and print length of each sentence

```
function calculateLen(sen) {
  let sentences  = sen.split('.')
  sentences.map((sentence)=>{
    console.log(sentence.length)
  })
  
}
```

Comment: map should be used for array alterations instead of looping.